# type color.Grayからtype intに変換する方法

Tags: go

皆様、よろしくお願いします。

現在GO言語を使用して、PNG画像からpixel intensityを取り出したいのですが、問題があり、ここで質問させていただきます。

以下がコードとなります。

```
package main

import (
            "bytes"
            "io/ioutil"
            "fmt"
            "image/color"
            "image/png"
        )

import "github.com/harrydb/go/img/grayscale"

func main() {

  FName_BG := "test.background.png";
  data_BG, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(FName_BG)
  img_BG, _ := png.Decode(bytes.NewReader(data_BG))
  grayImg_BG := grayscale.Convert(img_BG, grayscale.ToGrayLuminance)

    MaxRowSize, MaxColSize := img_BG.Bounds().Max.Y, img_BG.Bounds().Max.X;

    for y := 0; y < MaxRowSize; y++ {
         for x := 0; x < MaxColSize; x++ {
             c1_bg := grayImg_BG.At(x,y).(color.Gray);
             fmt.Println(c1_bg)
         }
     }
}
```

上記のコードでは、PNG画像を一旦Grayscaleに変換して、pixel intensityを取得する事を試みています。

問題は、「fmt.Println(c1_bg)」で表示されるものは

```
{255}
{255}
{255}
{255}
```

のように、color grayで表示されてしまいます。これをただ単にintegerにしたいだけです。
（具体的には、{255} -> 255のようにしたいだけです。）

もしご存知の方がおられましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`color.Gray` の[定義](https://golang.org/pkg/image/color/#Gray)は以下のようになっているので、

```
type Gray struct {
        Y uint8
}
```

整数値を得たいだけなら `Y` を参照するとできます。

```
fmt.Println(c.Y)
```

([Go Playground 上のサンプルコード](https://play.golang.org/p/RHrQCpBxPzv))

Comment: ありがとうござます！定義は確認したのですが、これをどのように使えば（コードに書けば）よいのかがわかりませんでしたので、大変助かります。お手数をお掛けしました。ありがとうございました。